# Color title mapbox

Tags: mapbox, title

Does anyone know how to change the title color of a marker on a mapbox,
I would like home to be in blue, I tried to add paint : color-size:"blue", but it doesn't work,
thank you for your help!!

```js
    map.on('load', function () {
  map.loadImage(
  'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
  function (error, image) {
  if (error) throw error;
  map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
 
    map.addSource('points', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
      'type': 'FeatureCollection',
      'features': [
      {
      // feature for Mapbox
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [6.157902659395512,49.3612254277963],

        },
        'properties': {
        'title': 'Lieu de repas',
        'scale': 2,
    },
      }
      ]
      }
      });
 
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'points',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'points',
        'layout': {
        'icon-image': 'custom-marker', 
        'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
        "text-size": 28,
        'text-font': [
        'Open Sans Regular',
        ],
        'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
        'text-anchor': 'top',
        }
        });
}
);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly create an [HTML marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/custom-markers-gl-js/#add-html-markers) for that in a way similar to this:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = 'Lieu de repas';
el.style.color = 'blue';

new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat([6.157902659395512,49.3612254277963])
.addTo(map);
```